# Convert SQL to Linq - Where, in, Groupby and Having count

Tags: sql, linq, group-by, having-clause

How can I write this query from SQL to LINQ:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE np in 
(
    SELECT np FROM table
    GROUP BY np 
    HAVING COUNT(np) > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<Table>.GroupBy(x => x.np)
       .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
       .SelectMany(x => x)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Finally the query is this:  
var ld= (
        from c in lae
        group c by new { nro = c.np } into agrupado
        where agrupado.Count() > 1
         select agrupado.Key).ToList();
         )
-greetings